# How do I compare means when I have a sample and the whole population?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean, sample, population

I have the following didactical exercise to carry out:

### Scenario

I have the avg room price for all the hotels of my chain (32 observations of the 32 hotels). Then I have the avg room price for a sample of competitors (60 observations taken from a larger population).

### Problem

I would like to understand whether the avg room price of the hotels of my chain is equal to that of the competitors

### Proposed solution

First, I computed the average room price across all the hotels of my chain $p_a$. Since the entire population is known, I would say that there is no uncertainty here, this is the exact average.

Then I computed the average room price of the sample of competitors and the related std deviation ($\bar{p}_c$ and $\tilde\sigma_c$).

I performed a hypothesis testing with the null $H_0: p_c = p_a$ against the alternative $H_1: p_c \neq p_a$. The test statistic is then ($n=60$):
$$
t = \frac{\bar{p}_c-p_a}{\frac{\tilde\sigma_c}{\sqrt{n}}}
$$
If the associated p-value is sufficently low, I reject the null hypothesis.

Basically here I'm considering that the average room price of the hotels of my chain is known and well-established, hence I'm doing the hypothesis testing for a single population mean (the competitors' population). Do you think this is the right approach or shall I test a hypothesis about two population mean (this is the alternative that comes to my mind)

Thanks for any help, T.

Comment: The hypothesis testing for a single population mean is good. Need to pay attention  to the calculation of std deviation if the total number of hotels from competitors is limited, for example less than 500.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @a_statistician. What should I exactly pay attention to if the population is limited? How does this affect the computation of the std deviation? Thx, T.

Comment: It is called The finite population correction. See eq. 3.19 on page 3-15 of http://www.ph.ucla.edu/epi/rapidsurveys/RScourse/RSbook_ch3.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems completely reasonable to me.  It is what I would have done.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're *really* planning to use the statistic.

One thing that immediately comes to mind is that hotel prices depend heavily on location. So the price of a hotel room in NYC is apt to be much higher than the price of a hotel in Bismark, ND.

So a better statistic might be to do a paired T test, where the price for each of your hotels is compared to a comparable hotel in the same market place.

Comment: Dear @MaxW thanks for your reply, I totally agree with you. Actually, this is more a didactical exercise (worth to mention in the question), not a real-world situation. In this case, I just need to answer the question with no other data available. My doubt was specifically related to the fact that I have a complete view on a population on one side, and a sample on the other.